# Fetch JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data fast api

Tags: python, json, fetch, fastapi

Hi i got a python fast api backend server.

```
   @app.get("/getName")
    async def getName() -> JSONResponse:
    data_sniffer = DataSniffer()
    data = json.dumps(data_sniffer.get_data())
    print(data)


    return JSONResponse(content=data,headers={'content-type':'application/json'})
```

this is the console output of data :{"first_name": "test"}

My Frontend Code looks like this

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function query() {
      const options = {
        method: 'GET',
        mode: 'no-cors',
        headers: {
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
          'Content-Type': 'application-json',
        },
      };

      const res = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:3000/getName', options);
      console.log(res);
      const data = await res.json();
      console.log(data);
    }

    query();
  });
```

but i get following error message SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
my network response looks like this:
"{"first_name": "test"}"

Has anyone a clue why fetch cant parse the json?

Comment: I all ready tried  `return json.dumps(data_sniffer.get_data())` and it didn't work.  `return {"first_name": "test"} ` didnt work to.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who has the same issue what worked for me is I moved my Backend folder to the root directory of my Frontend and removed the mode no-cors of the fetch request. I installed the no cors app and now it works. I think the mode no-cors broke my request.